# ESP32 String error when assigning value to it

Tags: arrays, string, xmlhttprequest, response, esp32

**Hello,**
I have problems with strings in my sketch. I assingn values to my string (for example tempStrReturn) in the functions setNr1, setNr2. If i pass the value 1 to the function i get "" or "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" when there should be 1. I don't understand why this is happening.

in the loop function i call setNr1("1"),setNr2("1"),... to test it. The output shows this:

```
192.168.43.140
Function setNR1............
Got: 0
NR1 int: 0
tempStrReturn before:
tempStrReturn after:
Function setNR2............
Got: 1
NR2 int: 0
tempStrReturn before:
tempStrReturn after: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Function setID...........
String id: ID
Set msgId to: 0
Set msgPos to: 1
Function setNR1............
Got: 1
NR1 int: 1
tempStrReturn before: ID
tempStrReturn after: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Function setNR2............
Got: 1
NR2 int: 1
tempStrReturn before: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
tempStrReturn after: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Function setH...........
nr1: 1
nr2: 1
Created value: 11
Original value in string: 0
nrX: 0 nrPos: 1 Value i want to enter: n/x-www-form-urlencoded
Value afther assignment: n/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

First time the function setNR1 is called the tempStrReturn is empty and after assignment is also empty. In the function setNR2 there is the application/x... mishmash. I dont use the tempStrReturn, shes just there for showing the error.

My arduino/esp code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESPAsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <FS.h>
#include <Wire.h>

const char* ssid = "Ti";
const char* password = "1234567891234";
// Stores LED state
String ledState;
// Create AsyncWebServer object on port 80
AsyncWebServer server(80);

#define ledPin 2  //BuiltInLed is inverted
#define countMax 2500
#define multiplyMax 100 
int count = 0, multiply = 0, msgDel = 0;
int nr1=0, nr2=0,msgPos, msgId, msgVar;
String inOut[10][10];
String tempStr1, tempStr2, tempStrReturn;
bool oneShot = false;


//***************************************

/*Set value of String[] on the nrPos to val*/
void inOutSet(int nrX, int nrPos, String val)
{
  Serial.print("Original value in string: "); Serial.println(inOut[nrX][nrPos]);
  Serial.print("nrX: ");Serial.print(nrX);Serial.print(" nrPos: ");Serial.print(nrPos);
  Serial.print(" Value i want to enter: "); Serial.println(val);
  inOut[nrX][nrPos] = val;
  Serial.print("Value afther assignment: ");Serial.println(inOut[nrX][nrPos]); 
}

String inOutGet(int nrX, int nrPos)
{
  return inOut[nrX][nrPos];
}


String dataRequest(int roomNr) 
{
  tempStrReturn = "";
  Serial.println("Preparing to send data as word...");
  Serial.print("Value in TempStringReturn before: "); Serial.println(tempStrReturn);
  tempStrReturn = "g" + roomNr;
  tempStrReturn = tempStrReturn+".";
  Serial.print("Adding g and . : "); Serial.println(tempStrReturn);
  nr1 = 0; nr2 = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  {
    Serial.print("Data Request: "); Serial.println(msgId);
    tempStrReturn = tempStrReturn+inOut[roomNr][i];
    Serial.print("Ading value from inOut: "); Serial.println(tempStrReturn);
  }
  Serial.print("Returning value: ");
  Serial.println(tempStrReturn);

  return tempStrReturn;
}

//saves value to nr1 as int
String setNr1(String var)
{
  Serial.println("Function setNR1............");
  Serial.print("Got: "); Serial.println(var);
  nr1 = var.toInt();
  Serial.print("NR1 int: "); Serial.println(nr1);
  Serial.print("tempStrReturn before: "); Serial.println(tempStrReturn);
  tempStrReturn = nr1+"";
  Serial.print("tempStrReturn after: "); Serial.println(tempStrReturn);
  return nr1+"";
}

//saves value to nr2 as int
String setNr2(String var)
{
  Serial.println("Function setNR2............");
  Serial.print("Got: "); Serial.println(var);
  nr2 = var.toInt();
  Serial.print("NR2 int: "); Serial.println(nr1);
  Serial.print("tempStrReturn before: "); Serial.println(tempStrReturn);
  tempStrReturn = nr2+"";
  Serial.print("tempStrReturn after: "); Serial.println(tempStrReturn);
  return nr2+"";
}

//Creates values for the array
String setID()
{
  Serial.println("Function setID...........");
  msgId = nr1;
  msgPos = nr2;
  nr1 = 0; nr2 = 0;
  tempStrReturn = "ID";
  Serial.print("String id: "); Serial.println(tempStrReturn);
  Serial.print("Set msgId to: "); Serial.println(msgId);
  Serial.print("Set msgPos to: "); Serial.println(msgPos);
  return "ID";
}

//Creates value from nr1 and nr2
String setH()
{
  Serial.println("Function setH...........");
  msgVar = (nr1*10)+nr2;
  Serial.print("nr1: "); Serial.println(nr1);
  Serial.print("nr2: "); Serial.println(nr2);
  nr1 = 0; nr2 = 0;
  if (msgVar >= 99)  {  msgVar = 100;  }
  Serial.print("Created value: "); Serial.println(msgVar);
  inOutSet(msgId, msgPos, msgVar+"");
  return "H";  
}

String getIO()
{
  nr1 = nr1/10;
  return dataRequest(nr1);
}

String processor(const String& var){
  Serial.print("Processor in: ");  Serial.println(var);
  return var;
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Filling the inOut array
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
      inOut[i][x]= "0";
    }

  }


  if(!SPIFFS.begin()){Serial.println("\nSPIFFS chyba!"); return;}

  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

  // Print ESP32 Local IP Address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Route for root / web page
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.html", String(), false, processor);//change
  });

  //route to favicon
  server.on("favicon.ico", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/favicon.png", "image/png");
  });

  // Route to load style.css file
  server.on("/style.css", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/style.css", "text/css");
  });

  // Route to javascript
  server.on("/main.js", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/main.js", "text/javascript");
  });


// Nr1 of the msg
  server.on("/0", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr1("0").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/1", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr1("1").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/2", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr1("2").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/3", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr1("3").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/4", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr1("4").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/5", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr1("5").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/6", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr1("6").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/7", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr1("7").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/8", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr1("8").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/9", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr1("9").c_str());
  });
// Nr2 of the msg
  server.on("/X0", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr2("X0").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/X1", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr2("X1").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/X2", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr2("X2").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/X3", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr2("X3").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/X4", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr2("X4").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/X5", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr2("X5").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/X6", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr2("X6").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/X7", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr2("X7").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/X8", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr2("X8").c_str());
  });
  server.on("/X9", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setNr2("X9").c_str());
  });
//end commands for use the nr values
  server.on("/ID", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setID().c_str());//Set ID nr
  });
  server.on("/H", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", setH().c_str());//Set value to id
  });
  server.on("/G", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", getIO().c_str());//Get value
  });

  // Start server
  server.begin();
}


/*-------------LOOP---------------*/
void loop() {
  count++;
  if (count > countMax)  {    multiply++; count = 0;  }
  if (multiply > multiplyMax)
  {
    if (!oneShot)
    {
      setNr1("0");
      setNr2("1");
      setID();
      setNr1("1");
      setNr2("1");
      setH();
      oneShot = true;
    }

    if (nr1 != 0 || nr2 != 0)
    {
      msgDel++;
      if (msgDel > 5)
      {
        nr1 = 0; nr2 = 0;
        Serial.println("DELETING...");
        msgDel = 0;
      }

    }

    //delay(60000);
    multiply = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: First i had an int array of 100 places. That worked without problems. But i then realised that i need to show also messages on the page. Thats why i used Strings.  on most places i need to store value 0-100, but on some i need to store info. If i use two dimensional araray i would need to have char inOut[100][]...or?
To store for example "0.100.0.0.Something.0.1.UP.0.50"

Comment: I just want to highlight that many of your functions declare a local variable and you are trying to return that variable at the end of the function, you need to understand the ["Scope of variables"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c/) that when you exit the function, the memory of that local variable get free up, even though the content might still be there, it is not safe and reliable to access what has been returned anymore. This happened in your `dataRequest()`, `perTo500()` and `inOutGet()`. This might not be the reasons that caused your problem, but you need to know.

Comment: Is it a bad practice if i use one global temporary variable in multiple functions instead of multiple local temporary variable in each function? I know what you mean but i thought that i save memory this way. In the inOutGet i use the tempStr1 this way. But the question is why it works when i use the function inOutSet() manuali in loop and why the array overruns (i think) when the program uses it.

Comment: You can either use a global var or make the local var within the function as `static`.

Comment: I edited the arduino code to return values via global variables but it did not fix the problem i am having. The inOutSet functions writes other staff from the memory to the inOut[x] string

Comment: Helo, i remade the code and simplified it. But the problem stays the same.

Comment: Hint: printout `tempPos` value in every step, you will find what wrong. This code to be honest is the wrong approach for what you want to achieve, it will be better and easier to index if you use a two-dimension array `inOut[10][10] = { {0,0,0,....}, {0,0,0...}, ... }`, to set a value would be a simply` inOut[msgID][msgPos] = msgVar`.

Comment: I used the two dimensional array before. I changed it because of this error. I thought that somehow my array owerflows. I changed it back and i wrote more printouts. Error remains.It seams that i cannot assingn values to strings. The string seems to read wrong memorry in the flash. I tryed another ESP but its the same.

Comment: When i change the values i want to assign to the string, the value mishmash in the strings changes. With the same numbers the string value has always the same mishmash.

Comment: Don't have any ideas? If i print it before its empty. After __tempStrReturn = nr1+"";__ the print out is __application/x-www-form-urlencoded__ or something else depending on the number in the nr1.